# body / container background does not fill height of screen

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

Novice developer, really frustrated with this and looked for answers on stack but not found any yet!

I have a site here: https://andymay101.github.io/emilyandywedding/
Code is here. There is a div container with a background image inside the body with the 5 menu items navigation.

Looks fine when I resize in browser on my tablet/desktop but when I navigate to on mobile there is blank white space and the whole website is not resizing to fit. already tried adding min-height 100% to body,

Pic attached, any advice appreciated!
[mobile screengrab of website index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUQrY.jpg)

Comment: This happens because the page content is not enough to fill it up so the footer does not stay at the bottom of the page. The white part you see is the background color for the `<body>` tag. There a couple of ways to fix this but that depends on how you want to do it. For a very quick hacky method you can use `.container {
  min-height: 80vh;
}` If you want to do it in a less hacky manner you need to add a bit of script to your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `min-height: calc(100vh - 302px);` to `.container`, it will take 100% of screen height minus `302px` (the sum of vertical paddings, header and footer height).

Answer (score 0):

Add these two meta tags along with small css.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1"/>
```

```css
.container {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1"/>
 
    <title>Andy and Emily's wedding</title>
    <link href="https://andymay101.github.io/emilyandywedding/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class=headerimg>
        <span class=headertext>Andy and Emily's wedding</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class=box>
          <span class"boxtext"><a href="venuedetails.html" target="_blank">Venue details</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class=box>
          <span class"boxtext"><a href="RSVP&accomodation.html" target="_blank">RSVP and accomodation</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class=box>
          <span class"boxtext"><a href="www.codeacademy.com">Wedding gifts</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class=box>
          <span class"boxtext"><a href="www.codeacademy.com">Suggestions box</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class=box>
          <span class"boxtext"><a href="Pictures.html" target="_blank">Pictures</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```